# docker-machine ssh into Vagrant VM failing

Tags: docker, ssh, vagrant, virtualbox, docker-machine

I have two vagrant VMs running Ubuntu16.04 over VirtualBox with docker installed. I want to create an overlay-network for the docker containers running on these two VMs. Hence, I followed the tutorial [here](http://blog.scottlowe.org/2015/08/04/using-vagrant-docker-machine-together/).

I have created the VMs and tried to run `eval "$(docker-machine env mh-keystore)"`. However, it failed with the following error:

```
Error checking TLS connection: Error checking and/or regenerating the certs:
There was an error validating certificates for host "172.28.128.5:2376": dial tcp 172.28.128.5:2376: getsockopt: connection refused
You can attempt to regenerate them using 'docker-machine regenerate-certs [name]'.
Be advised that this will trigger a Docker daemon restart which might stop running containers.
```

I then tried to regenerate the certificates as mentioned in the error. However, it fails to establish ssh connection to the VM.

```
Regenerating TLS certificates
Waiting for SSH to be available...
Too many retries waiting for SSH to be available.  Last error: Maximum number of retries (60) exceeded
```

I can still vagrant ssh to the VMs. Can somebody help me use the vagrant VMs using docker-machine.

Comment: Restart your computer. VirtualBox bug. Hate it personally.

Comment: Tried restarting. It's still failing.

Comment: I'll suggest tryingVirtualBox 5.0.20 then.

Comment: I am using the latest version: 5.1.14

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I faced a similar issue "waiting for ssh to be available"  and it turns out to be unsigned drivers in the network stack installed by some corporate proxy interception software called proxycap that were causing virtualbox to error when setting up port forwarding from the localmachine into the boot2docker vm. Check you VM machine logs and look for an error message while setting up port forwarding. It should also list the unsigned drivers causing errors and then you just need to uninstall the corresponding application.